# Recursively go up to find Makefile and compile

Tags: compilation, directories

The problem with `M-x compile` is that if the `Makefile` isn't in the current directory, it fails.

I'd like to have a function that recursively goes up to find a `Makefile` and run `make` from this directory.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668928/invoking-makefile-in-the-project-root-directory-from-subdirectory-from-emacs), but it's path-specific, and it's something I have to think about running.

Comment: If you are using `projectile` there are ways to compile from `projectile-project-root`. For instance, https://github.com/abo-abo/helm-make

Comment: @abo-abo I hadn't tried projectile! It seems that `projectile-compile-project` does what I want. But I'd like to have something without this dependency, if possible.

Comment: thanks, projectile-compile-project works for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are looking for the function `locate-dominating-file`. Here is the emacs documentation for this function:

> `(locate-dominating-file FILE NAME)`
>
> Look up the directory hierarchy from `FILE` for a directory containing
>   `NAME`. Stop at the first parent directory containing a file `NAME`, and
>   return the directory.  Return `nil` if not found. Instead of a string,
>   `NAME` can also be a predicate taking one argument (a directory) and
>   returning a non-nil value if that directory is the one for which we're
>   looking.

Using this, abo-abo's answer can be shortened to

```
(defun desperately-compile ()
  "Traveling up the path, find a Makefile and `compile'."
  (interactive)
  (when (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (cd (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile"))
    (compile "make -k"))))
```

Comment: Nice! This function does a similar thing to my loop, but in a well-documented and edge-case handling way. I'll make sure to add it to my recipe list, thanks.

Comment: Nice! vim has a similar function named [`findfile`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#findfile()), I was surprised emacs didn't have it.

Comment: Isn't there something similar to lisp's `let`? You're running `locate-dominating-file` twice.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yes, you could use let. I was typing the answer in directly without testing and figured this was less likely to have misplaced parentheses :)

Comment: I wish I could up vote this answer more. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Recursive compile, no dependencies attached:

```
(defun desperately-compile ()
  "Traveling up the path, find a Makefile and `compile'."
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (while (and (not (file-exists-p "Makefile"))
                (not (equal "/" default-directory)))
      (cd ".."))
    (when (file-exists-p "Makefile")
      (compile "make -k"))))
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: OK, just be careful with the end condition of the loop. If you're on Windows, you might get an endless loop.

Comment: Side question: why are you using `with-temp-buffer`?

Comment: Yeah I don't care about windows, but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I use `with-temp-buffer`, because `default-directory` is buffer-local. I don't want to change it for the current file.

Comment: You could have simply bound default-directory.

Comment: @jch Actually, my way looks simpler, code-length-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using `let` and interactively editable command:

```
(defun make-project (cmd)
  "Traveling up the path, find a Makefile and `make'."
  (interactive (list (read-string "make command: " "make -k")))
  (let ((make-dir (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile")))
    (when make-dir
      (with-temp-buffer
        (cd make-dir)
        (compile cmd)))))
```